# Factorial Rings and The Axiom of Choice

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

It is shown in Lang's Algebra (and many other books I assume) that:

if A if a principal entire ring, then A is a factorial ring.

The proof uses Zorn's Lemma. Is this theorem equivalent to the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lang uses Zorn's lemma only in the step that nonzero nonunits in a PID admit irreducible factorizations (not the uniqueness of irreducible factorizations, once we know such factorizations exist).  The way he uses Zorn's lemma, I think, is excessive.  What follows is how I work out the existence of irreducible factorizations when I teach the abstract algebra class.

Claim: In a PID which is not a field, any nonzero nonunit is a product of irreducibles.

We will use the following lemma (which is not Zorn's lemma).

Lemma: If $R$ is an integral domain and $a \in R$ is 
a nonzero nonunit which 
does not admit a factorization into irreducibles then 
there is a strict inclusion of principal ideals 
$(a) \subset (b)$ where $b$ is some other nonzero nonunit which 
does not admit a factorization into irreducibles.

Proof of lemma: By hypothesis $a$ is not irreducible, so (since it is 
neither 0 nor a unit either) there is some factorization
$a = bc$ where $b$ and $c$ are nonunits (and obviously are 
not 0 either).  If both $b$ and $c$ admitted 
irreducible factorizations then so does $a$, so 
at least one of $b$ or $c$ has no irreducible factorization. 
Without loss of generality it is $b$ which has no 
irreducible factorization.  Since $c$ is not a unit, the inclusion 
$(a) \subset (b)$ is strict.  QED lemma.

Now we can prove the claim.

Proof of claim: Suppose there is an element $a$ in the PID which 
is not 0 or a unit and has no irreducible factorization. 
Then by the lemma there is a strict inclusion 
$$
(a) \subset (a_1) 
$$
where $a_1$ has no irreducible factorization.
Then using $a_1$ in the role of $a$ (and the lemma again) 
there is a strict inclusion 
$$
(a_1) \subset (a_2) 
$$
where $a_2$ has no irreducible factorization. 
This argument (repeatedly applying the lemma to 
the generator of the next larger principal ideal) 
leads to an infinite increasing chain of principal ideals
$$
(a) \subset (a_1) \subset (a_2) \subset (a_3) \subset \cdots 
$$
where all inclusions are strict.  (At this step I suppose you may say we need the Axiom of Choice to get an infinite ascending chain, but it's only *countably* many choices, so really not the full thrust of Zorn's lemma and in any case it feels like a less pedantic use of Zorn's lemma than the way Lang does this.) Such a chain of ideals is impossible in a PID.

Indeed, suppose a PID contains an infinite strictly increasing chain of 
ideals:
$$
I_0 \subset I_1 \subset I_2 \subset I_3 \subset \cdots
$$
and set
$$
I = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} I_n.
$$
This union $I$ is an ideal.  The reason is that 
the $I_n$'s are strictly increasing, so any *finite* set 
of elements from $I$ lies in a common $I_n$. 
Therefore $I$ is closed under addition and arbitrary multiplications from 
the ring since each $I_n$ has these properties. Because we are in a PID, $I$ is principal: 
$I = (r)$ for some $r$ in the ring.  But because 
$I$ is the union of the $I_n$'s, $r$ is in some $I_N$. 
Then $(r) \subset I_N$ since $I_N$ is an ideal, so 
$$
I = (r) \subset I_N \subset I, 
$$
which means
$$
I_N = I.
$$
But this is impossible because the inclusion $I_{N+1} \subset I$ 
becomes $I_{N+1} \subset I_N$ and we were assuming 
$I_N$ was a proper subset of $I_{N+1}$. 
Because of this contradiction, nonzero nonunits in a PID without 
an irreducible factorization do not exist.  QED

Lang's argument only uses the axiom of choice in a countable way, as above, but the way he pulls it in makes the application of Zorn's lemma feel a lot more fussy.

Comment: You are using Dependent Choice, rather than Countable Choice, since the later choices depend on the earlier choices. The DC principle is intermediate in strength between Countable Choice and full AC.

Comment: Good Answer! This proof isn't even more difficult than the version where the axiom of choice is used. Why would an Author include a proof which depends on the Axiom of choice when such a simple proof which doesn't depend on it is available? 

Comment: Actually it seems like Lang's proof, dryer as it may be, uses countable instead of dependent choice because it doesn't build a chain of ideals one containing the other. Instead it just says, assume there's an ascending chain of ideals without a factorization into irreducibles...

Comment: Stankewicz, that sounds like DC rather than countable choice. You need DC rather than $AC_\omega$ to know that well-foundedness is equivalent to having no chains. (And if you turn the order upside down, that is what the argument seems to amount to.)

Comment: I never paid too close attention to the different versions of Zorn's lemma except for the distinction between making countably many choices vs. uncountably many.  I can use this application to remember what Dependent Choice is about (sort of). 

Comment: Very nice answer, by the way! The way I think about DC is that it is about countably many choices, but countably many *in succession*, just as in this example. It is often this version of choice that is used to build ascending sequences as you did or descending sequences of nested balls in a metric space, and so on. So it is often DC rather than $AC_\omega$ that is needed in these contexts.

Comment: Does this answer the question of whether the ring theorem is equivalent to DC? Can you prove DC from the theorem on rings? I thought this (except for the distinction between AC and DC) was what the original question was about. 

Comment: Daniel, Lang's proof and the one I wrote above both use a weak form of AC, so it's not accurate to say the proof I wrote doesn't depend on AC and Lang's proof does. Both do. If I compare them I would say that Lang's argument for the existence of irreducible factorizations in a PID is more opaque, and why would an author write such an argument?  He may have preferred the  concise application of Zorn's lemma as a better fit for the approach he was taking throughout his book (where Zorn's lemma is used elsewhere too).  He also may not have thought about trying to make this proof seem simpler.


Comment: The reason I wrote the above proof is not because I was trying to simplify what is in Lang, but because I was teaching the course using Dummit and Foote's book and noticed their reasoning behind existence of irreducible factorizations in PIDs is wrong. (Look on p. 288 of their 3rd edition and think carefully about the first paragraph.) I aimed to fix what D&F were trying to do, rather than just pull another book off the shelf and use its argument instead.  This was about three  years ago (and I just cut and pasted what was in my .tex file to generate the answer here when I read the question).

Comment: Gerry, since the ideals in a PID each only require a single generator, whether or not they're constructed that way at first, my gut feeling is that Dependent Choice is not a consequence of irreducible factorizations in all PIDs.  Hopefully Joel or others more expert on such matters than I can follow up. 

Comment: Gerry, this answer answers the question about whether the fact is equivalent to AC, and it is not, since it is provable from DC, which is weaker than AC. But you are right, the answer raises the question whether the fact is equivalent to DC. 

Answer (score 6):

This is an extended comment on Keith's answer:

Another way to think about Keith's argument (or the more general argument for the existence of minimal primes in Noetherian rings) is that one constructs a tree as follows: beginning 
with an ideal $I$, if it not prime then we may find $J_1, J_2$ properly containing $I$
such that $J_1 J_2 \subset I$, and we make a "factorization tree" joining $I$ to $J_1$
and $J_2$, and then iterate this procedure.

Noetherianness says that each branch of the tree has finite length, and since each
edge has finite valence, the whole tree is finite, hence we eventually must reach prime
ideals, and we find a finite collection of prime ideals $P_i$ whose product is contained
in $I$.

The fact about trees being used can be phrased (in the contrapositive) as:
an infinite tree with every vertex of finite valence has an infinite branch.  (This has a name, which I forget; it is also what underlies the proof of Bolzano--Weierstrass.)
Now the proof of this fact uses DC (as far as I can tell), and it's probably well-known
to logicians exactly whether or not it is equivalent to DC (or, at any rate,
exactly how strong it is).

The question then becomes whether we can model any tree (whose internal vertices have
valence 3) as a factorization tree (in a PID, say, although the possibility of allowing
more general Noetherian rings seems reasonable, at least if it helps to give a positive
answer).

Added: The result on trees is called Koenig's lemma. (Thanks to Artie Prendergrast-Smith for this.)

I should also note that my original movitation for formulating the above argument was similar to that of Keith: the usual proof of the existence of minimal primes in Noetherian rings uses Zorn's lemma and has a non-constructive feel, whereas the above reformulation feels more concrete.

Comment: I think the fact in question is known as Kőnig's Lemma.

Comment: It is true that you use DC to find the infinite branch, but you are also using AC to build the tree in the first place, since for each I you have chosen $J_1$ and $J_2$. In the case of the question, this amounts to $|R|$ many choices, and this may not be possible just from DC. So I'm not sure that your last paragraph is correct.

Comment: DC is equivalent to the assertion that every tree $T$ in which every node has at least one immediate successor (no need for finiteness) has an infinite branch. Each node of the tree points at the allowed "next" choices, and so the infinite branch is the sequence of choices.

Comment: Dear Joel,

Thanks for the corrections and comments.

Comment: Dear Joel, But, if I fix a choice of $I$, isn't it just a question of using DC to construct the tree?

Comment: Yes, that seems right: by DC you successively select the branching ideals at level $n+1$, given the tree up to level $n$ already selected. So this way of running the proof is just using DC after all. Alternatively, if you give up on finite-branching, you can make a tree that allows all possible ways to factor (not using any AC principle), and then apply DC to get the branch. (But this would be closer to Keith's argument.)

Comment: Dear Joel,  Thanks for your further comment.  The argument I gave and Keith's are indeed essentially the same.  (And just as Keith's argument is rewriting of a more "abstract" Zorn's lemma argument, mine is a rewriting of the more typical Zorn's lemma argument used to construct minimal primes.)  The reason I gave this argument is in part because I thought it might be possible to model a given tree in a ring as a factorization tree, and thus answer the (DC analogue) of the original question.