# Does ZF prove that all PIDs are UFDs?

Tags: set-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic

Main Question:

Does ZF (no axiom of choice) prove that every Principal Ideal Domain is a Unique Factorization Domain?

The proofs I've seen all use dependent choice.

Minor Questions:

Does ZF + Countable Choice prove all PIDs are UFDs?

Does ZF prove "If all PIDs are UFDs, then [some choice principle]"?

(If anyone knows how I could force line breaks to put the questions on their own lines, please tell me.)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. I'm also pretty sure this is a duplicate question.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24556/factorial-rings-and-the-axiom-of-choice/24559#24559

Comment: Gjergji, that's a more nicely put together proof than the others I've seen, but it still uses dependant choice.

Comment: While this is very similar to the question cited, I don't
see it as identical. This question amounts roughly to
is "PID => UFD" equivalent in ZF to some choice principle.
It's maybe more a question for logicians than algebraists.

Comment: Re line breaks, <br /> will force a line break.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ZF alone does not prove that every PID is a UFD, according to [this paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?aid=2076124): Hodges, Wilfrid. *Läuchli's algebraic closure of $Q$.* Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 79 (1976), no. 2, 289--297. [MR 422022](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=422022).

One result in this paper is the following:

> COROLLARY 10. Neither (a) nor (b) is provable from ZF alone:
> (a) Every principal ideal domain is a unique factorization domain.
> (b) Every principal ideal domain has a maximal ideal.

By the way, I didn't know the answer to this question until today. To find the answer, I consulted Howard and Rubin's book *Consequences of the Axiom of Choice*. (Actually, I did a search for "principal ideal domain" of their book using [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YXaVkHPQED4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false).)